# Why after first click, i need to click two times to reverse

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

**So my problem is that when i click on a radiobutton to add the class "completed", it does what is suposed to do, but when i want to remove it, i need to click two times, i don't know why. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you**

> html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Todo App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="TodoApp.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <!-- ------ Meta Tags ------ -->
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="topImage">
      <h1 id="topImage-title">T O D O</h1>
      <img onclick="test()" id="moon" src="images/icon-moon.svg">
      <img src="images/bg-mobile-light.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">  
    </div>

    <div class="newToDo">
      <input onclick="addTask()" id="ready" type="radio" name="ready">
      <input type="text" name="todoTask" id="todoTask" placeholder="Create a new todo...">
    </div>

    <div id="tasksBox">
      <div class="newTasks">
        <input onclick="completeTask()" type="radio" class="bttComplete" name="bttComplete">
        <span>Complete Online Javascript Course</span>
        <div onclick="deleteTask()" class="delete"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="jquery_library/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="TodoApp.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

> css

```
.completed{
    background-image: url(images/icon-check.svg);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

> javascript

```
function completeTask(){ 
  $(".newTasks").click(function(){
    if ($(this).children().hasClass('completed')){
      $(this).children().removeClass('completed');
    } else {
      $(this).children().addClass('completed');
    };
  });
}
```

Comment: As written, `completeTask()` runs each time the `.bttComplete` input element is clicked, and on each occasion another click handler is attached to the `.newTasks` container. 
This is almost undoubtedly not what you want. 
You probably want to attach a click handler once after initial page load, and allow it to do whatever is necessary without attaching any more click handlers.

Comment: In other words don't mix inline `onclick` and `$(selector).click(func..`. Use one or the other

Comment: Thanks to both,  Roamer-1888, and,  charlietfl, i don't know if i did what you wanted but, your answers, shore helped me fin what i needed. I removes the onclicks and used jquerie, click event/function. Either way its working better than before, so thank you.